# Running a script does not stop in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to run this query but it takes so long and my log file grows until there's no space left.
Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

```
select
    company.id, company.title, company.RegistrationDate, news.description, news.CompanyId
into
    dbo.newCompany
from
    dbo.Company, dbo.News
where
    RegistrationTypeId = '6' 
    or RegistrationTypeId = '11' 
    or RegistrationTypeId = '12'
    and news.CompanyId = company.Id
```

Comment: You are creating a cartesian product, use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: You can also simplify using `IN`, i.e. `where RegistrationTypeId in ('6', '11', '12')`.

Comment: `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`. Use parentheses!

Comment: Test the query without `into dbo.newCompany` to validate that it returns the results you want.  Once you perfect the joins and validate you're getting the correct data, then re-add the `into` clause

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be something like this :

```
select
    company.id, company.title, company.RegistrationDate, news.description, news.CompanyId
into
    dbo.newCompany
from
    dbo.Company company

JOIN dbo.News news ON news.CompanyId = company.Id
where
    RegistrationTypeId INT (6,11,12)'6'
```

Depending on your need, the JOIN can be LEFT, RIGHT,INNER: [Joins (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017)